# Class of functions for which the integral of the reciprocal is equal to integral of the original function

Tags: integration, density-function

If I know that for $f$ the following always holds:
$$f(\pmb{x}) > 0, \pmb{x} \in [0,1]^d$$
$$\int_{[0,1]^d}f(\pmb{x})\,d\pmb{x} = 1$$

I am interested for what class of functions the following also holds:
$$\int_{[0,1]^d}\frac{1}{f(\pmb{x})}\,d\pmb{x} = 1$$

Clearly if $f$ is constant ($f = 1$) then the first statement holds, since:

$$f(\pmb{x}) = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{f(\pmb{x})} = f(\pmb{x})$$

Are there more functions for which:

$$ \int_{[0,1]^d}\frac{1}{f(\pmb{x})}\,d\pmb{x} = \int_{[0,1]^d}f(\pmb{x})\,d\pmb{x}$$

Comment: Is the condition $\int f=1$ crucial for you ? Or do you "only" want to solve $\int f=\int 1/f$ ?

Comment: @fonfonx I think OP is thinking about probability density functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi (x)=\frac 1 x$ is a strictly convex function on $(0,\infty)$. $\phi (\int f) \leq \int \phi(f)$ which means $\frac 1 {\int f} \leq \int \frac 1 f$ and equality holds only when $f$ is a constant. The constant has to be $1$ of course.

Comment: If we relax the condition $\int f=1$ we can obtain more functions. For example $f(x)=2$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $f(x)=1/2$ on $[1/2,1]$.